# P tags appearing lower in firefox than in internet explorer, using CSS

Tags: css

I made a website that looks perfect on Internet Explorer, but when it is loaded with Firefox, certain elements are out of alignment.

For example, a p tag that would appear on the coordinates 20, 20, would appear in firefox on the coordinates 20, 40. For some reason, firefox changes the 'top' attribute of my p tags, such that they appear "lower" in firefox, than in ie. Please note that the 'left' attribute' remains unhindered, but the value for the 'top' (or y coordinate) is increased by about 20 pixels, everytime!

I would like to know why my P tags appear in their proper locations in Internet Explorer, but are lower in firefox?

Below is the code I used for each p tag. If you were to use this same code in a web page, you would see clearly that the p tag appears lower in firefox, than in i.e. everytime.

```
p.myparagraph
{position: absolute;
 left:     20px;
 top:      170px;
 width: 20px;
 height: 19px;
 background-color:0033dd;
}
```

**Why are my p tags appearing 30 pixels lower in firefox, than in Internet Explorer?**

Comment: You should fix that `background-color` css property, you forgot the `#`, it should be `background-color:#0033dd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each browser has its own CSS applied by default. To counter this, it is good practice to use some sort of CSS normalization (as pointed out by @You) before applying custom CSS. **CSS normalization is recommended over an outright reset** because it

- Preserves useful defaults, unlike many CSS resets.
- Normalizes styles for a wide range of elements.
- Corrects bugs and common browser inconsistencies.

Source: [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)

Also, do check out [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/). It offers that plus a lot more, including IE6+ compatibility/fallbacks etc.

If not that, you could use a basic CSS reset,

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, 
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   font: inherit;
   vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
   display: block;
}
body {
   line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
   list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
   quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
   content: '';
   content: none;
}
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Source: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Browser default are there for a reason. If you use a CSS reset, you should remember to set new sensible defaults (e.g. `margin:0` on `p` is probably only sensible if you also `text-indent` it). This effectively renders the reset useless, but meh.

Comment: That's a meyerweb v 2.0 reset, it would be nice to mention the original author's credits even if he put it in public domain - see http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @You, I generally use Initializr. I knew that basic resets were there so I Googled for one and pasted the first that I could find.

Comment: @fvu, I totally agree. Adding that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply abhshkdz, you've totally helped me out. :)

Comment: @abhshkdz: The point still stands, though. Granted, Initializr uses the H5BP CSS which is more sensible, but that's [CSS normalization](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) not an outright reset. I honestly don't get why people keep recommending resets over normalizing.

Comment: @You: Did not know about CSS normalization. Thank you. :)
Will improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a reset stylesheet then styling everything yourself.

My reset stylesheet styles a ton of tags (including P) with vertical-align: baseline;

That might help.