# Slider image and background repeat?

Tags: html, css

I have a slider that for some reason is half obeying margin 0?
Also, is there anyway I can make the top bar background not have such a large white border around it? I'm trying to make it start right underneath the browser url bar but it seems to leave a fairly large gap? 
http://ispiked.net/tests

Comment: You need to learn about CSS normalization/reset. Go through this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387456/p-tags-appearing-lower-in-firefox-than-in-internet-explorer-using-css/11387498#11387498

Comment: I suggest you to learn to use developer console. For example, you can hover with a mouse on a P tag in your code and instantly see that the P tag has a margin which is causing the white background at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the div with `class="oneByOne1"`. That should fix the slider.

As for the top bar, add `margin: 0;` to both the `body` element and the `p` element inside `.topbar` - afterwards you might want to add something like `padding-top: 15px` to that same `p` element.

Comment: Thanks! Although there's still a fairly large gap even after adding margin: 0; any ideas?

Comment: You haven't added `margin: 0` to the body element yet. Try it and report back.

Comment: Doh! sorry saw text-align:center; and for some reason for I had already done it? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score -1):

> Also, is there anyway I can make the top bar background not have such
>   a large white border around it?

tried CSS like

```
html, body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

to reset the layout at the beginning?