# Why does Firefox CSS Debugger not display P element default margin?

Tags: css, firefox

I just spent an hour troubleshooting an issue I had were all my paragraph elements were shifted down.

This happened after I moved the design from jsfiddle.net to my web host.

I killed an hour before I finally realized I needed to insert

```
p{margin:0px;}
```

and all was well...well still off by 1px;

Questions:

Why did this error not occur in jsfiddle.net?

Why does FF CSS Debugger not let me know that there is a margin in there or where it came from.  I don't know what is was set to but it was not 0px;

I'm trying to learn from "my mistakes" so I can know what to expect next time.

Comment: Possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387456/p-tags-appearing-lower-in-firefox-than-in-internet-explorer-using-css/11387498#11387498

Comment: It's the same browser..the inconsistent behavior is not explained by that solution.

Comment: Nor does it explain the reason why FF does not display the margin property though it is clearly set to something.

Comment: Even after applying my solution the elements are still shifted up by 1px;

Comment: [Edward Casey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Cayce), are you *listening*... (Edward: *I cannot answer without real demo code and/or liiiiiiinks...*)

Comment: I have no idea what to post...I think jsfiddle.net does some sort of automatic resets...that in a normal page do not get done.

Comment: Can you, I don't know, *give us the jsFiddle link at least*? This question at this point is wavy-handed astronautatin'. If we can't replicate and/or see the actual markup and CSS that produces your problem, `Not Constructive` or `Too Localized`. Take your pick.

Comment: I have to much code 1000 lines + in my fiddle...I don't have time to break it up... + solution found...it just seems standard that browser don't report defaults...I guess I'm suppose to pull out a ruler ( the kind that measures pixels) and measure the screen.

Comment: Sorry, that's beside the point. Did you click the `Normalized CSS` checkmark, make sure it's unchecked in the fiddle? This automatically inserts a reset stylesheet in the background. I forget it all the time. This isn't per se a Firebug issue; without more information, it's impossible to blame anything but that checkbox.

Comment: !! I didn't see that...I am blind...thank you!

Comment: Well, now that @abhshkdz's initial comment proved correct, see these two fiddles, one with and one without the `Normalize CSS` checked: [with Normalize](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/DxFa2/) and [without Normalize](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/DxFa2/1). You'll see a difference. Note, not all CSS resets are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web browsers set their own default values for rendering HTML elements. This includes margins, paddings, font sizes etc. When you create a HTML document with no CSS you can see lists, paragraphs and headings are formatted in a default way.

Debuggers tend to show the values that **you** have applied to the document in your CSS.

To get around these sorts of inconsistencies (browsers use different defaults) some people use a 'reset' CSS file that removes this behaviour by setting as much as possible to 0.

Take a look at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: But my inconsistency was on the same browser and version.....when i moved from jsfiddle.net to displaying in full screen...for some reason jsfiddle seemed to set my p margin to 0px perhaps it internally has a reset or something.

Comment: In that case I would imagine that jsfiddle.net was most likely applying some CSS you were unaware of.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - Why not, y'know, *provide an actual testcase* in jsFiddle and out and *give us that to review*? Guesswork is a poor foundation for learning.

Comment: I suspect the real problem was what @abhshkdz alluded to in his comment under the question; ie, `Normalized CSS` was selected in the suspect jsFiddle.

Comment: @Gibbs, [CSS normalization](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) should be used rather than an outright reset!

Comment: @abhshkdz I don't disagree but I thought a reset example would provide more insight in this case.

Comment: Good info...but basically...I like to know how ALL my code works...so I'm going to use my own "resets" as you all say to get rid of browser defaults for only the tags that I use in my code...so far all I've needed is the p tag....very simple code I have.